# Why do we focus on faith in Jesus' death and resurrection vs other kinds of faith?

Tags: faith

A Baptist website explains: "The Bible tells that there is one way to be saved and it is through believing Jesus died for your sins and asking Him to be your Savior."

Now if this is a true statement that "there is one way to be saved" how does the Centurion receive salvation before Jesus died for all those sins?

> Now when Jesus had entered Capernaum, a centurion came to Him, pleading with Him, 6 saying, “Lord, my servant is lying at home paralyzed, dreadfully tormented.” 7 And Jesus said to him, “I will come and heal him.” 8 The centurion answered and said, “Lord, I am not worthy that You should come under my roof. But only speak a word, and my servant will be healed. 9 For I also am a man under authority, having soldiers under me. And I say to this one, ‘Go,’ and he goes; and to another, ‘Come,’ and he comes; and to my servant, ‘Do this,’ and he does it.” 10 When Jesus heard it, He marveled, and said to those who followed, “Assuredly, I say to you, I have not found such great faith, not even in Israel! (Matthew 8:5-10 NKJV)

The text clearly does not say anything about Jesus Dying on the Cross. I want to know why faith is placed on Jesus Dying on the Cross in comparison to the type of faith shown by the Centurion?

Comment: It's right there in the text. Jesus says "I'll come to your house." The Centurion says "Not necessary, but only speak a word, and my servant will be healed."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trivial and shows a lack of research effort. The answer is plainly in the quoted text.

Comment: @fredsbend The text clearly does not say anything about Jesus Dying on the Cross. I want to know why faith is placed on Jesus Dying on the Cross in comparison to this perspective?

Comment: Are you thinking of the centurion who was present at the Crucifixion and said "Truly this man was the Son of God"?

Comment: Why would this have anything to do with that in the first place? The centurion had faith that Jesus had the power to heal his servant, despite a lack of proximity. There is nothing in the passage about Jesus' death, so why would you think that relates to this?

Comment: That is the point. The Protestants moved away from the Catholic Church because of justification by faith. But faith in their definition does not relate. For their faith is on the cross. This passage however describes a different kind of faith, and the two grow in different directions.

Comment: @MattGutting The Centurion in question is the one described in the question.

Comment: OK, next question: what exactly do you mean by "placing faith in Jesus dying on the cross"? Are you asking whether there are other ways of declaring one's faith in Jesus that don't **specifically** refer to his death on the cross? I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: @MattGutting A person that believes that Jesus was God, and that he died, and that by his stripes we where healed, and believes that he was raised from the dead, who believes this with all their heart mind and soul, and who listens to christian music, and goes to church, and reads the bible all day long, is absolutely not saved from the arguments. This is what I mean by faith in the cross.

Comment: Yet if one study's Denial and the stages of grief, one can learn acceptance, the truest definition of faith. For those that accept are on the good ground, and can accept the seed, and has protected the seed from the storm of doubt. Like this: If the Air Conditioner was to break, I could choose to not believe it, then casting me into anger. Yet if I can accept that the air conditioner is not working, and can trust that God renews all things then I do not enter anger, and my attitude/spirit remains Holy. Can you see the two types of faith now? I'm sorry if I did not ask the question well.

Comment: You're now asking two very different things: how/did the centurion have faith in Jesus' death on the cross? and why do we focus on faith in Jesus' death and resurrection vs other kinds of faith. Which one do you want to ask?

Comment: "That is the point. The Protestants moved away from the Catholic Church because of justification by faith." Have a look at Romans 4.

Answer (score 6):

## Faith = Belief/Trust in Jesus as the Son of God

The problem with your question is that you’re assuming that “faith” is “faith in Jesus dying on the cross,” but that is neither explicitly said, nor does it make sense in the context of the passage or in the context of the entirety of the New Testament.

The Greek word translated “faith” here ([πιστις, 4102](http://www.biblestudytools.com/lexicons/greek/nas/pistis.html)) means “trust, belief, faith, conviction of the truth.” “Faith in Jesus” is not “faith in Jesus dying on the cross” but “faith/trust that Jesus is who he said he was.” This is what faith means nearly everywhere in the New Testament when it is connected to Jesus.

> “I have not found such great faith, not even in Israel!”

Jesus praises the centurion because he has faith in Jesus as one with absolute authority over the universe. This has nothing to do specifically with Jesus dying on the cross. The importance of the cross is that Jesus allowed himself to be murdered, but because he was righteous, he was raised from the dead. Our “faith” is always *in* Jesus as Lord, not in anything less.

Comment: +1 Well said! Faith is not faith in Christ's death on the cross. Faith is faith in Christ! And if one believes in Jesus Christ, one should also believe in His death and resurrection. And His actions, journey, words etc. This question is indirectly stating that before Jesus died, no one had "faith" since Jesus had not been crucified on the cross yet....

Answer (score 2):

The centurion showed his faith by believing that Jesus has the power to *heal* and that He has *authority* over all things, including himself.

Notice the word **authority**, which is a prominent theme in this passage. Jesus is King. But His kingship had not been made fully manifest before His death and subsequent resurrection. He lived His life on earth as a lowly **servant**. He was born in a manger, a most humiliating birth. And he died by crucifixion, a most humiliating death. If we fast forward to the events after His resurrection, and shortly before His ascension, He declared, "All power is given unto me in heaven and in earth" (Matthew 28:18). The original word for *power* here is the same as that used for *authority* in the passage you quoted. Now, as one who had not seen nor heard those words, it was great faith for the centurion to claim Jesus' authority over himself, and to place himself, being a centurion, in the position of a servant, just as Jesus did.

Also note that the servant could have died if Jesus did not intervene. But even God the Father did not intervene when Jesus was crucified. God withheld mercy to His own Son, in order that we may have mercy. We would all die in sin if Jesus did not die for us. "With his stripes we are **healed**" (Isaiah 53:5).

Comment: This answer show no connection between the Centurion's faith and Jesus Dying on the cross.

Comment: @Onlyheisgood. why do you suppose so?

Comment: Not from the angle that I am trying to explain. Some place their faith on Jesus dying for them. And although he did die for them and they are indeed saved because he died. This is a different type of faith. So technically you do point out a connection, but it is not what I mean.

Comment: So I should append to my first comment. "shows no connection between the types of faith". Your answer expands on only one of the perspectives, you see?

Comment: @Onlyheisgood. I have expanded my answer. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Yes by his strips we were healed, but the punishment is not taken away from us by this fact. The punishment "can" be taken away, and that is the difference. I will say it point blank so that their is no confusion at all. A person that believes that Jesus was God, and that he died, and that by his stripes we where healed, and believes that he was raised from the dead, who believes this with all their heart mind and soul, and who listens to christian music, and goes to church, and reads the bible all day long, is absolutely not saved from the arguments. This is what I mean by faith in the cross.

Comment: Yet if one study's Denial and the stages of grief, one can learn acceptance, the truest definition of faith. For those that accept are on the good ground, and can accept the seed, and has protected the seed from the storm of doubt. Like this: If the Air Conditioner was to break, I could choose to not believe it, then casting me into anger. Yet if I can accept that the air conditioner is not working, and can trust that God renews all things then I do not enter anger, and my attitude/spirit remains Holy. Can you see the two types of faith now? I'm sorry if I did not ask the question well.

Comment: Do you see that you still only expanded one of the two perspectives?